# JQuery footer div Parallax scrolling effect using body scroll value

Tags: jquery, css, parallax

I tought it would be simple to do a minor parallax effect on a footer 'div' background, using the 'body' scrollTop() to change the background-position

This is my trial, but the background of the footer 'div' doesn't move. I don't see what I'm doing wrong here:

### HTML is like

```
<body>
<div class="footer_parallax"></div>
</body>
```

### JS is like

```
$('body').scroll(function(){
var x = $(this).scrollTop();
$('.footer_parallax').css('background-position','0% '+parseInt(-x/10)+'px');
});
```

codepen here: http://codepen.io/ssstofff/pen/zxXyMp

Comment: You need to listen for the scroll even on the `window` and not on `html` or `body` (`$(window).scroll(...)`). Beside that you should not do changes on every scroll, because this event might be send with really short intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since codepen uses iframes I think theres some problem with fetching scroll element via `body` tag. When I changed it to `window` it worked.

Here is full snippet (CSS method notation changed):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var x = $(this).scrollTop();

  $('.footer_parallax').css({'background-position': '0% '+parseInt(-x/10)+'px'});

});
```

Comment: No this is not a syntax error (a syntax error is invalid code). Beside that   you can do both`$().css(prop, value)` or passing an object `$().css({prop: value});`.

Comment: You are right, I changed my answer. Codepen is now updated, but I belive at some point there where missing one of the parentheses so codepen marked comma as unexpected char. Maybe that was part of the problem.